# BLE Characteristic not reading full string at once

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral, hm-10

I m sending data from slider and buttons to Arduino through Hm10, but the problem is my string is getting read in two parts, it is getting divided from second last characteristic to a new line string.

```
 func writeValue(data: String){
    let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("data string is" , data)

    //change the "data" to valueString
    if let blePeripheral = blePeripheral{
        if let txCharacteristic = txCharacteristic {
            blePeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: txCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            print(valueString!)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if switchUI.isOn {
        print("On ")
       // writeCharacteristic(val: 1)
        writeValue(data:"tp1z  ")
    }

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print("characterstic value is" , characteristic.value!)
    if characteristic == rxCharacteristic {
        if let ASCIIstring = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            characteristicASCIIValue = ASCIIstring
            print("Value Recieved: \((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")

            NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil)

        }
    }
}


 func updateIncomingData () {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: nil , queue: nil){
        notification in
        let appendString = "\n"
        let myFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)
        let myAttributes2 = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: myFont!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
       let attribString = NSAttributedString(string: "[Incoming]: " + (characteristicASCIIValue as String) + appendString, attributes: myAttributes2)

        let newAsciiText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.consoleAsciiText!)
        self.baseTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: characteristicASCIIValue as String , attributes: myAttributes2)

        newAsciiText.append(attribString)

        self.consoleAsciiText = newAsciiText
        self.baseTextView.attributedText = self.consoleAsciiText
        print("incoming")

    }
}
```

I am not able to understand why is it breaking my string from second last character.

Comment: How long is your string?  You can only send about 20 bytes at a time using a GATT characteristic.  It doesn't really matter *why*, you just need to handle the fact that it may take several transmissions

Comment: I don't think that its a byte problem coz m sending strings less than 20 bytes and suppose if i send string of 6 bytes then it will send 2 string 4 bytes and then 2 bytes but m not understanding the reason

Comment: It doesn’t matter about the reason. It is just a stream of bytes. You place meaning on a newline character but it is just another byte. You need to write code that gathers the incoming data and identifies the sequences you are interested in. A finite state machine is one approach you could investigate

Comment: check my updated code , it still gives the same problem

Comment: What problem? What output or result do you get? What do you want?

Comment: I am getting two strings, my string is getting divided from second last character, suppose I send tp0z then m getting two string one is tp and second is 0z though I want it to read full string rather than dividing.

Comment: You can’t change that. You need to reassemble the strings on the receiving end.

Comment: do you mean inside did value update function

Comment: You can do it there or somewhere else. I would probably create some object that represents your “command” or whatever.

Comment: can you give some answer with the help of code, it would be better to understand.

Comment: @SomaSharma have you found any solution?

Comment: @SaurabhJain I used to empty chars for my work at the end.

Comment: @SomaSharma ok..let me try

Comment: @SomaSharma you should give your own answer

Comment: @SaurabhJain done, do let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @SomaSharma sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, I used to empty characters as it was breaking my string from second last character like below:-

```
writeValue(data:"tp1z  ")
```

It worked for me.